# In Scala, read a file where specified path includes multiple environment variables

Tags: file, scala, environment-variables

For a file path name such as

```
val path = "$HOME/projects/$P1/myFile.txt"
```

is there a simpler way to resolve the path and read `myFile.txt` than this,

```
import java.io.File
val resolvedPath = path.split(File.separator).map{ s => 
      if (s.startsWith("$")) sys.env(s.drop(1)) 
      else s }.
    mkString(File.separator)

val res = io.Source.fromFile(resolvedPath).getLines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have seems good to me, but if you are so inclined or need to do something quickly, you could use [`Process`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) to get the return of executing a bash command:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val cleanedPath = Seq("bash", "-c", "echo " + path).!!.trim
```

You can even use this idea to read the file if you want:

```
val text = Seq("echo", "-c", "cat " + path).!!
```

One difference between these and your code is that your code will throw an exception if an environment variable is missing, while `bash` returns an empty string for that variable.  If you wish to mimic that, you could use `sys.env.get(s.tail).getOrElse("")` instead of `sys.env(s.drop(1))` or use the dictionary `val myEnv = sys.env.withDefaultValue("")`.

Answer (score 1):

See [System.getenv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--). You'll be able to find the variables and replace them with the value to resolve your path.